# reverse content of file block by block

Tags: c, linux

So here is the program to reverse content of a file block by block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BS 12

void reverse(char * buffer, int size)
{
  char tmp;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
  {
    tmp = (char)buffer[i];
    buffer[i] = buffer[size - i - 1];
    buffer[size - i - 1] = tmp;
  }
}

int main (const int argc, const char** argv)
{
  if(argc != 3)
    exit(-1);

  char * buffer = malloc(BS);
  FILE * f1, * f2;
  f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  f2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

  fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);

  long i = ftell(f1);
  // long f1_len = ftell(f1);
  // unsigned char tmp;
  int if_end = 1;
  int need = 0;
  int count;


  do
  {
    i = i - BS;
    if(i < 0)
    {
      need = BS - abs(i);
      i = 0;
    }
    else
      need = BS;

    fseek(f1, i, SEEK_SET);

    if(if_end) // strip EOF
    {
      count = fread(buffer, need - 1, 1, f1);
      if_end = 0;
    }
    else
      count = fread(buffer, need, 1, f1);

    reverse(buffer, count);
    fwrite(buffer, count, 1, f2);

    if(i == 0)
      break;
  }while(i > 0);


  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);
  free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

testfile:

```
$ xxd testfile
0000000: 6162 6364 6566 670a                      abcdefg.
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test testfile testfile2
$ xxd testfile2
0000000: 61                                       a
```

Any idea where is wrong? I have been debugging this for long time.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to trace the execution of your program? What did you find?

Comment: Note that `EOF` is not actually a character that is stored in a file.

Comment: @kaylum was just looking at that but some text files do store an EOF marker (say 0x1A), which would need to stay at the end.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, I guess that could be the case for legacy systems that use that for text files. Though I doubt that is the case here. At least OP will now be in a position to evaluate whether the EOF adjustment is really needed or not.

Comment: @kaylum, I agree. In addition to your point, the answer (almost) has it - swap the `size` and `count` arguments passed to `fread` and `fwrite`

Comment: The names `f1` and `f2`are wrong: they fail to represent the role of the object they provide access to. All of the code is wrong as presented: nowhere does it mention the purpose of any part of it - it may do just _anything_ without deviating from specified behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `fwrite` returns the number of successful blocks, not the number of bytes.

So `reverse(buffer, count);` needs to be `reverse(buffer,count * need)`

Similairly the write to the output needs to be  `fwrite(buffer, count * need, 1, f2);`

Comment: Or swap the `size` and `count` arguments passed to `fread` and `fwrite`.